# Accepting a dictionary as an argument with argparse and python

Tags: python, dictionary, argparse

I'm trying to accept an argument of type=dict with argparse but no matter the input it gives an error of invalid dict value.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse

MYDICT = {'key': 'value'}

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-m", "--mydict", action="store",
                    required=False, type=dict,
                    default=MYDICT)

args = parser.parse_args()

print args.mydict
```

This is what  happens when I try and pass a dictionary to the script

```
./argp.py -m "{'key1': 'value1'}"
usage: argp.py [-h] [-m MYDICT]
argp.py: error: argument -m/--mydict: invalid dict value: "{'key1': 'value1'}"
```

Looking at the documents I would think that this would be possible.

http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html

“Any object that supports the in operator can be passed as the choices value, so dict objects, set objects, custom containers, etc. are all supported.”

Comment: The line you quote from the documentation pertains to the "choices" keyword argument, which defines what values of the arguments are allowed. Passing a dict to choice is effectively equivalent to passing a list of the keys. Thus, passing "{ 'a':2, 'b':3 }" would restrict allowed arguments to your "--mydict" flag to "a" or "b".

Answer (score 101, accepted):

I do not think it is possible to pass a dictionary as an argument in the command line because there doesn't exist a conversion function from string to dict (**EDIT**: A hack *is* possible which gives similar behaviour, see below). What you are essentially telling python to do is:

```
dict("{'key1': 'value1'}")
```

Which if you try it out in the python console, does not work.

What the phrase:

*"Any object that supports the in operator can be passed as the choices value, so dict objects, set objects, custom containers, etc. are all supported."*

refers to is the **choices** argument that can be passed with the **add_argument** function - not to the **type** argument.

Your best bet is to probably accept your argument as a string and then convert it using the [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) capabilities of python:

```
parser.add_argument('-m', '--my-dict', type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()

import json
my_dictionary = json.loads(args.my_dict)
```

You can then pass a dictionary in the form of a string. You can try the json encoder/decoder out for yourself in the python console to see how it works:

```
>>>json.loads('{"value1":"key1"}')
{u'value1': u'key1'}
```

**EDIT**: hpaulj has pointed out to me that you can "hack" the *type* parameter by passing it *json.loads* which allows you to pass JSON that is similar looking to a dictionary.

```
import json
parser.add_argument('-d', '--my-dict', type=json.loads)
args = parse.parse_args()

mydict = args.my_dict  # Will return a dictionary
```

**NOTE**: The input format you pass is *not* the same as python dictionary but is probably similar enough for your use case.

The reason this works is actually quite interesting because internally argparse will just use the parameter value as a function to convert the argument. i.e. if type=int then it will use int(arg) or if type=json.loads then json.loads(arg)

This also means that you can pass any function which takes a single parameter in as the argument to type and perform custom conversions if you need to :)

Comment: `type=json.loads` works

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense since as I mentioned above,  the parameter passed to type is handled by placing the argument in the parenthesis. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily call that a "hack". It's actually how the type argument is supposed to work

Comment: would that take care of default values per key value?

Comment: Apparently  jason can decode with single quotes outside and double quotes inside the dict '{"value1":"key1"}' but not "{'value1':'key1'}"

Comment: In windows, pass ``-m {\"key1\":\"value1\"}`` in the terminal.(adding backslash ``\`` in front of ``"``, without spaces in the whole ``{}``  string).

Comment: If you want the string representation of the dictionary to be correctly formatted remember to have a look at `json.dumps(dictionary)`

Comment: It is worth taking a look at this blog post (not mine):
https://sumit-ghosh.com/articles/parsing-dictionary-key-value-pairs-kwargs-argparse-python/

Comment: Adding in that if you are passing booleans in your "dictionary" to use JSON format on the CLI (true/false and NOT True/False). It will auto-format to pythonic True False when parsed.