# Force a user to pass dictionary on command line

Tags: python, argparse, command-line-arguments

I want to pass a dictionary on command line. The following code fails:

```
import json
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Test Arg Parse')
parser.add_argument('-d', '--dict', type=dict, required=False)

variables = vars(parser.parse_args())
print json.dumps(variables)
```

When I'm running the program, it throws the following error:

```
C:\KTLO\bin>python TestProg.py -d "{'a':'b'}"
usage: TestProg.py [-h] [-d DICT]
TestProg.py: error: argument -d/--dict: invalid dict value: "{'a':'b'}"
```

**Edit 1**: Specifying 'json.loads' or 'dict' does not change the output and still it throws the error.

Comment: You need to make `json.loads` the `type`, it makes no sense as `default` and `dict` doesn't accept as string representation of a dictionary.

Comment: @Siva In the accepted answer, it is showing a hack, which actually doesn't work.

Comment: Passing `json.loads` as `type` isn't a hack, and it does work.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes. I copied the wrong code! Even with your suggested changes, it is throwing the same error. Can this be done?

Comment: It worked fine for me, so please give a [mcve].

Comment: @jonrsharpe It is not working for me. [code and output](http://hastebin.com/zejeqayife.tex). Can you share your version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116670/discussion-between-psychocoder-and-jonrsharpe).

Comment: Put it *in the question*, please, not on some random off-site text dump. I have undeleted my answer, your problem appears to be that your input isn't valid JSON. Strings *must* be quoted, using `"`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am able to run the above script on python 2.6.6. The same code throws an error on 2.7.

Comment: *"an error"*? Again, [mcve] please.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
python TestProg.py -d '{"a":"b"}'
```

single quotes are no valid json.

Comment: `C:\KTLO\bin>python TestProg.py -d '{"a":"b"}'
usage: TestProg.py [-h] [-d DICT]
TestProg.py: error: argument -d/--dict: invalid dict value: "'{a:b}'"
` Doesn't work

Comment: i guess additional your ``default=`` should be ``type=``, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18609361/893159

Comment: @psychoCoder note that you're quoting the whole object, not the keys and values in it.