# How to pass DAG params to a KuberenetesPodOperator as an argument?

Tags: python, kubernetes, airflow

Whenever the DAG is triggered using a custom JSON it should use those values in the `{{ params }}`. I'd like to send this dictionary with all it's keys and sub-dicts to a task which will process and check those values if they are correct.

I tried sending it without transforming, using `json.loads`, replacing the whitespace, it seems like nothing is working as `argparse` can't recognize the argument even though it works locally. Somehow airflow doesn't respect the changes I tried to make to this value.

How should I change the code in the DAG to be able to send the `{{ params }}` through argparse?

This is how the two scripts look using only minimal code (also without imports):

airflow dag:

```
with DAG(
    "pipeline",
    render_template_as_native_obj=True, # so that {{ params }} is a dict
) as dag:

    prevalidation = KubernetesPodOperator(
        task_id="pre-validation",
        name="pre-validation",
        cmds=["python3"],
        arguments=[
            "-m",
            "prevalidation",
            "--config",
            "{{ params }}",   # the params dict
        ],
        )
```

prevalidation.py:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--config")
    args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
    # won't get here when using from DAG, locally it works
```

Comment: are you trying to pass `dict` directly to your script `prevalidation.py`? if so then refere this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18609361/4593654

Comment: I tried converting it to a string using `json`, it works locally, but when I'm using it through airflow `argparse` won't recognize the argument as it were a different type, even after passing it through `json.dumps`

Comment: could you share the rendered template and logs from script when executing from airflow?